# Python: How to sort strings with regards to their trailing numbers?

Tags: python, sorting

What is the best way to sort a list of strings with trailing digits

```
>>> list = ['mba23m23', 'mba23m124', 'mba23m1', 'mba23m5']
>>> list.sort()
>>> print list
['mba23m1', 'mba23m124', 'mba23m23', 'mba23m5']
```

is there a way to have them sorted as

```
['mba23m1', 'mba23m5', 'mba23m23', 'mba23m124']
```

Comment: `sort(key=lambda s:int(s[6:]))` works as long as the prefix is always 6 characters.  Otherwise use `itertools.groupby` or a regex to separate the numbers from the non-numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a lambda (anonymous) function and `sort()`'s `key` argument:

```
ls = ['mba23m23', 'mba23m124', 'mba23m1', 'mba23m5']
ls.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split('m')[-1]))
print(ls)
```

Yielding:

```
['mba23m1', 'mba23m5', 'mba23m23', 'mba23m124']
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use natsort library.

```
from natsort import natsorted # pip install natsort
list = ['mba23m23', 'mba23m124', 'mba23m1', 'mba23m5']
```

output:

```
['mba23m1', 'mba23m5', 'mba23m23', 'mba23m124']
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a function to remove trailing digits and  return other part of the string. (Lets consider this function as f_remove_trailing_digits(s) )

you can use following function:

```
   def f_remove_trailing_digits(s):
           return s.rstrip("0123456789")
```

2. Then you can sort using this way

   list.sort(key=lambda x:f_remove_trailing_digits(x))